# Can not use Corel Draw 2020 Visual Studio editor to edit a VSTA application

Tags: c#, coreldraw, vsta

I want to use Corel Draw 2020 Visual Studio editor to write a script and it could start Visual Studio. But when I click the button "start", a dialog box will appear and show this error:

> Cannot start debugging. Pre-debugging negotiation with Host failed

I have no idea to solve it.

Comment: What is "Corel Draw 2020 Visual Studio editor"?

Comment: It's one of  CorelDraw 2020's options which could start visual studio 2019 to edit the VSTA applications for coreldraw 2020

Comment: I don't think CorelDraw is compatible with VS 2019 - what version of VS / VSTA do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run your VSTA program from Visual Studio. Run this "macro" from CorelDraw after editing and compiling your C# class.

[See picture] [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58kJB.png)

Comment: Can you clarify on what the macro should be?

Comment: I edited my post to show how to run a VSTA macro (script) from CorelDraw